# FVWM & FVWM-crystal installation on 12.04 Ubuntu Command-line-system

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line

I'm not sure if this question should be asked here, in this forum. If it is not, I'm sorry and please refer me to any place where it's appropriate to ask.

My question is: "How to install FVWM and FVWM-crystal on 12.04 Ubuntu command-line-system?" If possible, I'd love to have a step-by-step instruction. If these are too much to ask, then would it be possible for me to ask for the dependencies or packages to install before I can get to the FVWM desktop-environment?

Thank you very much for your time and effort in reading this question (and answer).

Comment: please don't blame me about that but, have you checked archlinux

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but: I've installed `fvwm` on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop system with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install fvwm
```